# What does the Ravana Samhita say about Rahu?

Tags: astrology, ravana, samhita, rahu

I can't read Hindi and Sanskrit.

Which of the signs of the zodiac is called Rahu's own sign or Rahu's exaltation sign in this edition of the Ravana Samhita?

https://archive.org/details/rXra_ravan-samhita-asli-pracheen-by-pt.-kishan-lal-sharma-manoj-publications-delhi

Comment: Rahu doesn't have exaltation position over any Sun sign, in Jyotish Shastra, in particular.  But, is the ruling entity of 3 Nakshatras namely, Swati, Shatbhisha & Ardra.

Comment: No, in various primary sources of jyotish, the exaltation sign of Rahu is indicated - https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-dc5858b581f78c9e410036799e1c709e

Comment: @John1980 Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra also talks about exaltation and debilitation of Rahu and Ketu

Comment: This is usually under the effect of other planets that exaltation occurs for Rahu. Will try to search shastra pramana for same tho.

Comment: Here, for example, shastra-pramana (Brihat Parāśara Horā Śhāstra By R. Santhanam) - https://ia803008.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/9/items/brihatparasarahorashastrabyr.santhanam/Brihat%20Par%C4%81%C5%9Bara%20Hor%C4%81%20%C5%9Ah%C4%81stra%20By%20R.%20Santhanam_jp2.zip&file=Brihat%20Par%C4%81%C5%9Bara%20Hor%C4%81%20%C5%9Ah%C4%81stra%20By%20R.%20Santhanam_jp2/Brihat%20Par%C4%81%C5%9Bara%20Hor%C4%81%20%C5%9Ah%C4%81stra%20By%20R.%20Santhanam_0464.jp2&id=brihatparasarahorashastrabyr.santhanam&scale=4&rotate=0

Comment: @John1980 Sir, the book mentiones the exaltation of Rahu for Mahadasha period only. Taurus or Vrishab sign, is ruled already by Shukra (Venus) & one sign can't be ruled by two deities. Thus, this is highly debatable that Rahu rules over Tauras even without Mahadasha periods.

Comment: The fact that Rahu and Ketu are the co-rulers of the various signs of the zodiac is stated in many classic jyotish texts. Even in Naadi-jyotish this is also a fact. It is only debatable which signs of the zodiac are co-ruled by Rahu and Ketu. Because in different texts, Rishis and Munis point to different signs of the zodiac. By default, in the classics it is stated that Rahu is similar to Saturn, and Ketu is similar to Mars, therefore the opinion of Parashara prevails, and in general Parasari-jyotish prevails, because it is best preserved and most texts are written on it.

Comment: For example, I read the English translation of Bhrigu Samhita Paddhati. It clearly shows that Rahu and Ketu give excellent results mainly in the signs of their exaltation. However, according to Bhrigu, these signs are Gemini and Sagittarius, in this he and Parashara differ in opinion.
And there is also Vasishtha Samhita, in which Vasishtha also claims about the sign of co-rule of Rahu and the sign of co-rule of Ketu, he agrees with Parashara.

Comment: @John1980 Rahu shows good signs in Saggitarus & Gemini because those are ruled by Jupiter & Mercury to whom he is akin. For example, he will be worst in Leo & Cancer as they are signs ruled by Sun &Moon, his sworn enemies. Thus, Rahu shows characteristics as per the ruler of the signs he enters. Becoz, he has ambiable relation wid Venus too he is favourable in Tauras. But, Rahu doesn't have his own sign over which he rules. This can be understood because, Rahu in all 12 signs can't produce his own independent effect, but Rahu itself gets influenced by the lord of tht particular sign he enters.

Comment: Rahu and Ketu do not give as good results in the signs of their friendly planets as they give in the signs of their exaltation. This can be easily verified by the classic Jyotish texts, which have already been mentioned in this topic. And the fact that Rahu and Ketu also produce the effect of the ruler of the house with which they are in conjunction or the dispositor - does not contradict the fact that they have their own signs, according to which they also produce results.

Comment: Lord Shiva himself, in Shiva Jataka 4 and Jyotisharnava Navanitam 5.14, states that Rahu and Ketu have their own exaltation signs.